# ColdFusion cfcase statements and referencing their variables?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-8

If you have code like so:

```
<cfcase value="Test">
   /**Do Stuff
</cfcase>
```

Is it possible to reference that value within the case statement?

I want to concatenate a list that can handle multiple cases and be able to dynamically reference the variables like so:

```
<cfcase value="Test,Another,Yes,No">
   <cfif this.value EQ 'Test'> blabla </cfif>
</cfcase>
```

I can't find anything that detailed about this for everywhere I have looked, just curious if it is even possible.

Comment: Nice examples...including the cfscript example below. I upvoted all of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can run multiple case statement in a `cfcase` tag:

```
<cfswitch expression="#URL.TestValue#">

    <cfcase value="Blue,Red,Orange" delimiters=",">
        <cfoutput>#URL.TestValue#</cfoutput>
    </cfcase>

    <cfcase value="Yellow">
        <cfoutput>#URL.TestValue#</cfoutput>
    </cfcase>

</cfswitch>
```

Answer (score 6):

Well... yeah... if your `<cfswitch>` expression was `#originalExpression#`, then the value that caused the case to trigger will be... `#originalExpression#`. There's no need to be tricky about it!

IE: you'll need to do something like this:

```
<cfswitch expression="#originalExpression#">
    <cfcase value="Test,Another,Yes,No">
        <!--- stuff common to all of Test,Another,Yes,No ---->

        <!--- stuff specific to various cases --->
        <cfif originalExpression EQ "test">
            <!--- do stuff ---->
        <cfelseif listFindNoCase("Yes,No", originalExpression)>
            <!--- do stuff ---->
        <cfelse>
            <!--- do stuff for "another" --->
        </cfif>
    </cfcase>
    <!--- other cases etc --->
</cfswitch>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible using ColdFusion tags. You can do something similar with `<cfscript>`

```
switch (expression)    {

    case "Test" :
       // Do some extra stuff
       // No break here

    case "Another" : case "Yes" : case "No" :
      // Do yet some normal stuff
      break;
    }
```

Disclaimer: I would **not** want to maintain this code